# How does abstract class call get a child value in constructor?

Tags: php, abstract-class

I am trying to use an in abstract class an non specify variable, that should be implemented by the child class.

I tried with abstract methods but it did not work.

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected abstract function foo($data);

    public function __construct($param) {
         self::foo($param);
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    public $propertie;

    protected function foo($data) {
         $this->propertie = $data;
    }
}

$fa = new ConcreteClass('banana');
echo $fa->propertie;
```

But this is the result:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot call abstract method AbstractClass::foo() in folder/folder/File.php on line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using self:: , typically a class static method, and did not invoke the parent class constructor.

Try this:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected abstract function foo($data);

    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->foo($param); // *** use $this, an instance method
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{
    public $propertie;

    public function __construct($param)
    {
        parent::__construct($param); // ** invoke the parent's constructor
    }

    protected function foo($data)
    {
        $this->propertie = $data;
    }
}
```